# Haskell read first n lines

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to learn Haskell to get used to functional programming languages.  I've decided to try a few problems at [interviewstreet](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4eac48496bee2) to start out.  I'm having trouble reading from stdin and doing io in general with haskell's lazy io.

Most of the problems have data coming from stdin in the following form:

```
n
data line 1
data line 2
data line 3
...
data line n
```

where n is the number of following lines coming from stdin and the next lines are the data.

How do I run my program on each of the n lines one at a time and return the solution to stdout?

I know the stdin input won't be very large but I'm asking about evaluating each line one at a time pretending the input is larger than what can fit in memory just to learn how to use haskell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `interact`, in conjunction with `lines` to process data from stdin one line at a time. Here's an example program that uses `interact` to access stdin, `lines` to split the data on each newline, a list comprehension to apply the function `perLine` to each line of the input, and `unlines` to put the output from `perLine` back together again.

```
main = interact processInput

processInput input = unlines [perLine line | line <- lines input]

perLine line = reverse line -- do whatever you want to 'line' here!
```

You don't need to worry about the size of the data you're getting over stdin; Haskell's laziness ensures that you only keep the parts you're actually working on in memory at any time.

EDIT: if you still want to work on only the first `n` lines, you can use the `take` function in the above example, like this:

```
processInput input = unlines [perLine line | line <- take 10 (lines input)]
```

This will terminate the program after the first ten lines have been read and processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a simple recursion:

```
getMultipleLines :: Int -> IO [String]
getMultipleLines n
    | n <= 0 = return []
    | otherwise = do
        x <- getLine
        xs <- getMultipleLines (n-1)
        return (x:xs)
```

And then use it in your main:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    line <- getLine
    let numLines = read line :: Int
    inputs <- getMultipleLines numLines
```